# Reordering Columns Based on Numerical Column Header

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code to reorder columns in an Excel model based on a number between 1 and 29 in Row 1 (column headers).

I will receive data from a client, and some of the columns will be relevant to what I need and the others won't.

The relevant columns get assigned a number between 1 and 29 while the irrelevant columns get no number (blank value in row 1).

As of now, this code works; it reorders the columns from 1 to 29 with appropriate spacing (i.e, if I have 1 and 4 but not 2 and 3, 1 will be in column A, 4 will be in column D, and columns B and C will be empty), and any column without a number is pushed after column AC.

This code only works if I have a column labeled 1 and 29. If I don't have a 29, the irrelevant columns occupy the columns between A and AC.

I attached some screenshots explaining it.

Screenshots of Macro Input and Output
[image]

If I want this macro to work, I have to manually add a column with "29" in row 1. How do I make it work even if I don't have a "29"?

```
Dim new_column_order As Variant, new_index As Integer
Dim found As Range, counter As Integer

new_column_order = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29")

counter = 1

For new_index = LBound(new_column_order) To UBound(new_column_order)

    Set found = Rows("1:1").Find(new_column_order(new_index), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, 
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        If found.Column <> counter Then
            found.EntireColumn.Cut
            Columns(counter).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        End If

        counter = counter + 1
    End If

Next new_index

Dim i As Long, j As Long
For i = Range("A1").value To Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).value
    j = Cells(1, i + 1) - Cells(1, i)
    If j > 1 Then
        Columns(i + 1).Resize(, j - 1).Insert
        i = i + j - 1
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: What version of Excel do you have? PowerQuery/Get&Transform can reorder columns quite easily.

Comment: Sounds a little lame, but you can cut/paste (rather than cut/insert) after adding 28 columns to the sheet, so all data can only appear in "AC" and further right without being placed forward.

Comment: *I have to manually add in a column with "29" in row 1*. Make VBA add that extra 29 is it not present. You can delete it later on with VBA

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add little more code and find max value and its column in 1st row. 
Then substitute 29 and that max value, result is number of rows you need to insert after max value column location. You will get situation like on your picture.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused. Could you post the code for what you're proposing?

Answer (score 0):

**Array approach**

This solution demonstrates the restructuring capability of the `Application.Index()` function (`[2]`) applied on a 2-dimensional data array (`[1]`) by one code line. In addition to the array reference itself, this function needs two further arguments:

1. a "vertical" array of all needed rows,
2. a "flat" array of the needed columns in any order.

Eventually all array items are written back to (any) range (`[3]`).

*Btw, looping through a range by means of VBA is time consuming, so I prefer array methods in most cases.*

```
Sub RearrangeColumns()
' Purpose: a) rearrange columns based on numerical headers
'          b) sort header columns to the left,
'          c) untitled columns after 29 columns to the right
  With Sheet1                                               ' worksheet referenced e.g. via CodeName

    ' [0] identify range
      Const lastCol& = 29
      Dim LastRow&
      LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row        ' get last row
      Dim rng As Range
      Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, lastCol + 1))

    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ' [1] get data
    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~
      Dim v: v = rng                                        ' assign to 1-based 2-dim datafield array

    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ' [2] restructure column order in array in a one liner
    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      v = Application.Index(v, Evaluate("row(1:" & LastRow & ")"), getColNums(v))

    ' [3] write data back to any sheet (<~ change to your needs)
      Sheet2.Range(rng.Address) = vbNullString                                    ' clear orginal data
      Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(v), UBound(v, 2)) = v      ' write new data

  End With

End Sub
```

**Help function `getColNums()` called by above main procedure**

The help function `getColNums()` simply returns an array of all valid column header numbers found in the current titles; it uses `Application.Match` to find occurrencies:

```
Function getColNums(arr) As Variant()
' Purpose: return array of found column number order, e.g. Array(3,2,1,4,6,5)
Dim titles                                                ' current titles
titles = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Application.Index(arr, 1, 0)))

Dim ColCount&: ColCount = UBound(arr, 2) - 1
ReDim tmp(1 To 2 * ColCount)                              ' temporary array to collect found positions

Dim c&, cc&, i&, pos
'a) left part (titled & numerically sorted columns)
For c = 1 To ColCount                                     ' loop through titles in intended order to allow sort
    pos = Application.Match(c, titles, 0)                 ' column number position in titles
    If Not IsError(pos) Then
        i = i + 1: tmp(i) = pos
    End If
Next c
'b) empty mid part
For c = i + 1 To ColCount
    tmp(c) = ColCount + 1                                  ' blank column reference 30
Next c
'c) right part (without column titles)
For c = 1 To UBound(titles)
    If Len(titles(c)) = 0 Then
        cc = cc + 1: tmp(ColCount + cc) = c
    End If
Next c

ReDim Preserve tmp(1 To ColCount + cc)                    ' remove empty elements
getColNums = tmp                                          ' return array with current column numbers (1-based)
End Function
```

Comment: @chrisphils26 Would appreciate feed back to my late solution to your restructuring problem based on arrays and the advanced possibilities of the Application.Index() function. Feel free to upvote if helpful :)